# How to install RISCV64 gdb?

Tags: gdb, apt, riscv

I'm trying to install a debugger for `riscv64-unknown-none-elf` on Ubuntu 20 with `apt-get`. What package do I need to install to get the `riscv64-unknown-none-elf-gdb` command?

Answer (score 0):

Normally `gdb` binary is the part of toolchain, you can install the `riscv` toolchain.
https://github.com/riscv/riscv-gnu-toolchain